# Can I use pinia getter as the first argument of Vue3's watch?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

### Summary

when setting a watch target as the first argument in Vue3 watch, can i input pinia getters?

### Environments

- vue: 3.2.13
- pinia: 2.1.4
- typescript: 4.5.5

### Description

when I referenced the getter of the pinia store object as the first argument to watch, a typescript error occurred.

> typescript error code: ts(2769)

#### Code

```js
watch(myStore.getExample, (newValue, oldValue) => {
 ...
})
```

i understand that **pinia getter is a readonly variable like vue3 computed**. 
since computed has a proxy pattern applied, doesn't it need to be exported as a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it yet, but I think that if you want to use `getExample` property inside your component and make it reactive, you have to convert it into `ref` first.

Here's an example:

```
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { watch } from 'vue'

const { getExample } = storeToRefs(myStore)

watch(getExample, () => {
    console.log('it's reactive!')
})
```

edit 1:

from the [docs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20extract%20properties%20from%20the%20store%20while%20keeping%20its%20reactivity%2C%20you%20need%20to%20use%20storeToRefs().%20It%20will%20create%20refs%20for%20every%20reactive%20property.%20This%20is%20useful%20when%20you%20are%20only%20using%20state%20from%20the%20store%20but%20not%20calling%20any%20action.):

```
In order to extract properties from the store while keeping its reactivity, 
you need to use storeToRefs(). 
It will create refs for every reactive property. 
This is useful when you are only using state from the store but not calling any action.
```

Comment: why do I need to convert to ref?

Comment: it's explained in pinia docs [here](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20extract%20properties%20from%20the%20store%20while%20keeping%20its%20reactivity%2C%20you%20need%20to%20use%20storeToRefs().%20It%20will%20create%20refs%20for%20every%20reactive%20property.%20This%20is%20useful%20when%20you%20are%20only%20using%20state%20from%20the%20store%20but%20not%20calling%20any%20action.)